# How to activate SSL in easyphp devserver

Tags: ssl, easyphp

I would like to activate SSL in devserver 16.1.1.

The reason is that I need to test the .htaccess that will automatically redirect to https. So it could be a fake/auto-signed certificate I don't care.

I already activated extension=php_openssl.dll in php config file but it does not work: https://localhost still returns an error.

Thank you

Comment: What error? Have you generated the keys? Google 'Generate self-signed ssl for apache', there are plenty of tutorials/references.

Comment: I get a usually error message from the browser "connexion failed"

Comment: You need to do better than that, as I mentioned what you've done so far? did you generated the ssl certificate, private key and public key using openssl command? What have you made changes on apache configuration files? It take more than just enable the openssl.dll in php.ini to setup ssl access. Provide the info or else no one would be able to help you.

Comment: I have just installed easyphp devserver and modified php.ini as mentionned, nothing else. That's why I ask the question: what should I do? Thanks

Comment: Ok I have followed this tutorial http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/apache-ssl-on-windows/ and I get an error 403 when I go to https://localhost . Any idea?

Comment: There are many openssl commands for verifying the configuration. But try to start with `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443` command to diagnostic the configuration.  If you don't see any error return, then the problem is at your browser configuration, or else you have something wrong on configuration the ssl.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have noticed that this 403 error is only with Chrome. It works when I go to 127.0.0.1 but when I go to localhost I get the 403 error. Whereas in Firefox both work. Anyway it is not any issue, I will put 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you please share how you were able to set it on 127.0.0.1 with us. Questions can be voted up now on SO specially when they are good or contains some sort of answers